# trying to return a variable value from a procedure in snowflake. And it is getting errored out

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dbo.test()
RETURNS varchar  null 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
execute as caller
AS 
$$
set MY_VAR =1;
return $MY_VAR;
$$
;
```

If I execute as below I am facing the error . Message as shown below
call  dbo.test();

```
//ERROR: JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in TEST at 'set MY_VAR =1;' position 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
RETURNS float not null 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
execute as caller
AS 
$$
var MY_VAR =1.1;
return MY_VAR;
$$
;


call <database>.<schema>.test();
```

gives:

```
1.1
```

so given you are trying to return a number value, I changed it to `float` instead of `varchar`, but after testing ether is fine.

But mostly I changed from `set` to `var` to declare your variable. The other valid keyword is `let`, which also works.

Comment: //Actually in one procedure I am calling other procedure where the reuslt is assgining to the P_DATALAKEPATH variable and the ouput of internal procedure is  "READ|WRITE|UPDATE" and i am trying to split the value and assigning to the MY_VAR variable and so on and i am getting error. Please help
  
  var p_sqlText = `CALL LS_${P_ENV}.dbo.dbo(:1,:2)`
        stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:p_sqlText,binds: ['1','2']   });
        rs = stmt.execute();
        rs.next();
        var P_DATALAKEPATH = rs.getColumnValue(1); 
        set MY_VAR=SPLIT_PART(P_DATALAKEPATH,'|',1);

Comment: @KartheekReddy are you suggesting you over simplified your question, and now your asked question has been answered, the answer does not help your unasked question and you would like that answered instead. I would suggest asking another question.