# Error: assigning a variable output to other variable in snowflake procedure

Tags: variables, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In one procedure I am calling other procedure where the result is assigned to the `P_DATALAKEPATH` variable and the ouput of internal procedure is  `READ|WRITE|UPDATE` and I am trying to split the value and assign to the `MY_VAR` variable which is giving an getting error. Please help

```
var p_sqlText = `CALL LS_${P_ENV}.dbo.dbo(:1,:2)`
stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:p_sqlText,binds: ['1','2']   });
rs = stmt.execute();
rs.next();
var P_DATALAKEPATH = rs.getColumnValue(1); 
set MY_VAR=SPLIT_PART(P_DATALAKEPATH,'|',1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of output variables is predictable, I suggest to not put multiple values in a single string and separate them by parsing the string in JS like you're trying to do.

Since your SQL generates a table, instead of putting everything in one column with a pipe separator, why not creating several columns in the output and get them back to your SP with `rs.getColumnValue(1)`, `rs.getColumnValue(2)`, `rs.getColumnValue(3)` etc?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing JavaScript and SQL in your code. This is SQL:

```
set MY_VAR=SPLIT_PART(P_DATALAKEPATH,'|',1);
```

You need to use JavaScript to split the value of P_DATALAKEPATH, and the get the first value:

```
var MY_VAR = P_DATALAKEPATH.split("|")[0];
```

Comment: @KartheekReddy so in the end your problem was the same problem as your original question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173025/trying-to-return-a-variable-value-from-a-procedure-in-snowflake-and-it-is-getti When people have answered your question you should mark the question as answered.